# How can we see RemoveDebris capturing a satellite with a net?

Tags: imaging, esa, removedebris-mission

The BBC's [RemoveDebris: UK satellite nets 'space junk'](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-45565815) says:

> The aptly named **[RemoveDebris satellite](https://www.surrey.ac.uk/surrey-space-centre/missions/removedebris) took a video of its net experiment**.
>
> The short sequence shows a small, shoebox-sized object tumbling end over end about 6-8m in front of the University of Surrey spacecraft.
>
> Suddenly, a bright web, fired from the satellite, comes into view. It extends outwards and smothers the box.
>
> "It worked just as we hoped it would," said Prof Guglielmo Aglietti, director of the Surrey Space Centre.
>
> "The target was spinning like you would expect an uncooperative piece of junk to behave, but you can see clearly that the net captures it, and we're very happy with the way the experiment went."

The linked article is extensive and has a nice animated video of the whole mission (unlisted in YouTube: [RemoveDebris Mission](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QUhCLTfXf0)) but so far I can't find a video or even a sequence of images of the net capture of the test vehicle.

**Question:** How can we see the video or image sequence of the RemoveDebris satellite capturing a satellite with a net?

**edit:** after I wrote this post, the BBC seems to have added a video clip containing a bit of the net capture, and a short interview. Either that or it did not display properly earlier (which also happens from time to time here).

**below:** "The net as it was stowed in its firing mechanism" Credit Airbus. From [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-45565815).

[image: RemoveDebris' net (Airbus)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw video is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvgctXXzIYA) and there's some more context in the video in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/SurreyNanosats/status/1042197398448234498).